# Fast lock for variables that are read a lot and may be changed from another thread occasionally

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm looking for a lock, that allows a thread-safe transition between the GUI and the back-end.

Just for a double, but I'm sure it will end up being used for other things.

Now this is the part I'm unsure of, on modern CPUs, can reading and writing at the same time cause a race condition? Or is it only when two threads try to write at the same time.

I've always encapsulated any variables that I cross threads with, in a template object, which allows me the same use but requires locking, here is the basics:

```
//=====================================================================================================
// Class to store a variable in a thread safe manner.
//=====================================================================================================
template <class T>
class ThreadSafeVariable
{
public:

  ThreadSafeVariable(const T & variable):
    _stored_variable(variable)
  {
  }

  ThreadSafeVariable():
    _stored_variable()
  {
  }

  //=====================================================================================================
  /// Returns the stored variable
  //=====================================================================================================
  T Read() const
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    return _stored_variable;
  }


  //=====================================================================================================
  /// Sets the variable
  //=====================================================================================================
  void operator = (const T &value_to_set)
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _stored_variable = value_to_set;
  }


  //=====================================================================================================
  /// Returns the stored variable
  //=====================================================================================================
  operator T() const
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    return (T) _stored_variable;
  }


  void SetFromString (const std::string & value_to_set);
  T operator ++ (int);
  T operator -- (int);
  std::string ToString() const;

  protected:
  T _stored_variable;
  mutable boost::mutex _mutex;
};
```

Would it be possible, to make a class like this faster, provided that only one thread was given the option of writing (that part would needed to be encoded by calling different functions).

Basically I've got a static function, that I want to keep static that varies based on a parameter I would like to change on the GUI but it's in a performance critical part of the software.

I'm aware of spin locks, atomics. But have never really used them. I guess a spin lock would be a waste of CPU and I'm not sure of the performance gains from atomics.

Comment: Did you mean to use something like [read/write lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) actually?

Comment: You may like to explore "spin locks" too.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `std::atomic<>`, it pretty much implements precisely the behavior you need. Don't reinvent the wheel.

The nice thing about `std::atomic<>` is, that it actually employs the hardware facilities for atomic reads and writes, so that all the basic instanciations of `std::atomic<>` are actually lockfree, which is a huge speed bonus. There are even a few preprocessor macros that signal which of the basic instanciations of `std::atomic<>` are implemented in a lockfree fashion, which allows you to select the best fitting lockless one (`ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE` is one of these, for example).

---

The following is an explanation of the possible race between a read and a concurrent write only. **Don't try to read this as instructions for doing anything outside of the language standard**. If you ignore the standard and nasal deamons appear, that's not in my department.

Regarding your question about whether there can be a race condition between a read and and write, that really depends on the circumstances. Generally, you can assume that a single read or write of a naturally aligned type that is natively supported by the machine will be handled in an atomic fashion. I. e., on a 64 bit machine you can expect reads and writes of `uint64_t` to be atomic if the `uint64_t` is aligned to an eight byte boundary. If these conditions are not met, you may end up in a situation where one half of the value you read from memory comes from the value before the write while the other half comes from the value that was written. For example, if you do this

```
while(1) {
    myGlobal = 0x0000000000000000;
    myGlobal = 0x0123456789abcdef;
}
```

concurrent to

```
printf("0x%016llu\n", myGlobal);
```

and `myGlobal` is *not properly aligned*, or is run on a 32-bit machine, you might find that you get an output of `0x0123456700000000`.

The C++ language is defined in a way that ignores these implementation details, so concurrent access of any variable that includes at least one write is considered a race condition. This is a bit far on the safe side, as the existence of `std::atomic<>` acknowledges. **It is also very dangerous to code that relies on these guarantees but does not use `std::atomic<>`**, because it allows the optimizer to skrew the assumptions of the programmer (more information on this can be found in this short article [Boehm.pdf](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf) , thanks to nosid for the link).

**Consequently, `std::atomic<>` is the only way to get lockless, threadsafe variables with the blessing of the C++ standard**.

Comment: The first part is okay. But the second part is more than questionable. You are missing the point. There are no _benign data races_. See https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf

Comment: @nosid I have taken a look at the link (which is generally quite good), and section 2.2 which applies to the problem at hand. And it pretty much gives the same conditions as I have given, though wording it quite differently. The text basically goes the same way as the standard, saying that you shouldn't assume a certain hardware, so you shouldn't assume any atomicity guarantees that it might in fact give. And modern hardware *does* give such guarantees **if the preconditions are met**. After all, `std::atomic<>` has to be implemented somehow...

Comment: `Generally, you can assume that a read/write of a naturally aligned type that is natively supported by the machine will be handled in an atomic fashion` - that may be a bit confusing. Reading would be atomic, writing as well, but read+write (as in the ++ operator) is not atomic and needs to be guarded.

Comment: No, it's not section 2.2 which applies to the problem at hand. It's the whole paper. It doesn't matter, if the machine guarantees _all or nothing_ operations. The compiler and the machine will do all kinds of optimizations, as long as they don't have a reason for not doing it. And these optimizations will break code, if there are data races.

Comment: @nosid I have already added a note about the danger of the optimizer (including the link you've given, thanks for that). I have also added a disclaimer to try to stop people reading that second part in a way which was entirely unintended. I hope, that satisfies your concerns.